# how to hide a folder in windows7 using command prompt?

Tags: windows

I need to hide a folder that is not visible to other than me and if anyone search the filename that are present inside that folder, they won't get the result. Likewise how to hide a folder using any software or command Prompt?

Comment: sounds like a superuser question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your folder name is XYZ and F is Drive name
attrib +s +h : It adds System and Hidden attribute to the file or folder.

```
“attrib +s +h F:\XYZ”
```

For unhide

```
“attrib -s -h F:\XYZ”
```

[Completely Hide a File or Folder](http://www.wikihow.com/Completely-Hide-a-File-or-Folder)

[How to Unhide Files/Folders:](http://www.passionateblogging.com/hide-files-folders-using-cmd/)

## [Software](http://download.cnet.com/Free-Hide-Folder/3000-2092_4-10617541.html)

## [Hide Folder software‎](http://en.softonic.com/s/full-version-free-hide-folder-software/windows-7)

Comment: For my knowledge I think this is the way to hide folder using cmd prompt

Comment: @1210dhana oh no you removed my answer useful.Better you can make upvote

Comment: @1210dhana enna achu..accepted answer and removing tick..

Answer (score 0):

Type "attrib +s +h F:\XYZ” (without quotes) and hit enter. Now your folder is now hidden.

To unhide folder use the same command but replace '+' with '-' on both flags 's' and 'h'. Example: Now again open RUN and reverse the command “attrib -s -h F:\XYZ”.(without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Check this for 3 different ways of hiding folder.
  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-quick-easy-ways-hide-folder-windows-7/

If you want to use any software, check this:-
  http://wise-folder-hider.en.softonic.com/

It can be done through notepad also, check this:-
  http://www.hitechnologic.com/2012/08/how-to-create-password-protected-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

In the general case this is not possible. The H flag hides the folder, but using most software tools this hiding is minimally effective. The folder is easily seen by setting the 'hidden items' flag in Explorer, or by using CMD DIR with /A:SH.

You can make a folder invisible if you manipulate the rights on the containing folder so that you are the only person who can see the contents. It will be invisible, and so will everything else!

If you're trying to hide things from other users of the computer, you're going to need to rethink your strategy. Trying to hide a folder is not the answer.